# NuxtJS3 + Nuxt auth-next - Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'options')

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxtjs3, nuxt-auth

I am using NuxtJS3 with @nuxtjs/auth-next and when I do `npm install` I get this error

> ERROR  Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'options')                                                                                    00:10:01
> at axiosModule (node_modules/@nuxtjs/axios/lib/module.js:12:13)
> at installModule (node_modules/@nuxt/kit/dist/index.mjs:416:9)
> at async initNuxt (node_modules/nuxt/dist/index.mjs:1825:7)
> at async loadNuxt (node_modules/nuxt/dist/index.mjs:1857:5)
> at async loadNuxt (node_modules/@nuxt/kit/dist/index.mjs:493:19)
> at async Object.invoke (node_modules/nuxi/dist/chunks/prepare.mjs:30:18)
> at async _main (node_modules/nuxi/dist/cli.mjs:50:20)

With this error I cannot start the application. I tried to look around on SO but with no luck. I tried to look at some known bugs also with no success.

This is my `package.json` file:

```json
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "build": "nuxt build",
        "dev": "nuxt dev",
        "generate": "nuxt generate",
        "preview": "nuxt preview",
        "lint": "eslint --ext .ts,.js,.vue, --ignore-path .gitignore . && prettier . --write",
        "format": "prettier . --write",
        "postinstall": "nuxt prepare",
        "prepare": "husky install"
    },
    "husky": {
        "hooks": {
            "pre-commit": "npm run lint"
        }
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^6.2.0",
        "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.35.1",
        "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.35.1",
        "@vue/eslint-config-typescript": "^11.0.0",
        "eslint": "^8.22.0",
        "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.5.0",
        "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.2.1",
        "eslint-plugin-vue": "^9.4.0",
        "husky": "^8.0.0",
        "nuxt": "3.0.0",
        "prettier": "^2.7.1",
        "typescript": "^4.7.4",
        "vite": "^3.0.9",
        "vite-plugin-eslint": "^1.8.1",
        "vite-plugin-vuetify": "^1.0.0",
        "vue-eslint-parser": "^9.0.3",
        "vuetify": "^3.0.1"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@mdi/font": "^7.0.96",
        "@nuxtjs/auth-next": "^5.0.0-1622020005.1b3f5f5",
        "@nuxtjs/axios": "^5.13.6",
        "@pinia/nuxt": "^0.4.6"
    }
}
```

This is my `nuxt.config.ts` file:

```js
import vuetify from "vite-plugin-vuetify";
import eslintPlugin from "vite-plugin-eslint";

// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/ban-ts-comment
// @ts-ignore
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  css: ["vuetify/styles"], // vuetify ships precompiled css, no need to import sass
  vite: {
    ssr: {
      noExternal: ["vuetify"] // add the vuetify vite plugin
    },
    plugins: [eslintPlugin()]
  },
  modules: [
    "@nuxtjs/axios",
    "@nuxtjs/auth-next",
    "@pinia/nuxt",
    // this adds the vuetify vite plugin
    async (options, nuxt) => {
      nuxt.hooks.hook("vite:extendConfig", (config) =>
        // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/ban-ts-comment
        // @ts-ignore TODO try to delete this ts-ignore after vuetify will be stable
        config.plugins.push(vuetify())
      );
    }
  ],
  /*
   ** Auth module configuration
   ** See https://auth.nuxtjs.org/api/options.html
   */
  auth: {
    strategies: {
      google: {
        client_id: "my id"
      }
    },
    redirect: {
      login: "/login",
      logout: "/",
      callback: "/login",
      home: "/"
    }
  },
  axios: {},
  alias: {
    pinia: "/node_modules/@pinia/nuxt/dist/pinia.mjs"
  }
});
```

I really do not know why I am getting this error. I tried to build it with yarn with no success. I also tried `@nuxtjs/auth` also with no luck. Is there a way to use NuxtJS auth with NuxtJS3?

Answer (score 1):

As of today, this is [the only auth module](https://github.com/sidebase/nuxt-auth) that can be used with Nuxt3 as [confirmed here](https://twitter.com/TheAlexLichter/status/1600933215405019173). The team is working on an official one, it's [on the roadmap](https://nuxt.com/docs/community/roadmap#-core-modules) but not done yet.

You can probably follow that [Github issue](https://github.com/nuxt-community/auth-module/issues/1805) to get some updates and essentially more info.

---

You can also try to google for a blogpost regarding that subject and implement it on your side with a composable and a few checks on a middleware.